# Ext JS 4.2 paging combo - how to skip to page

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, combobox

I have a Combo such as:

```
{
        xtype : 'combo',
        anchor : '70%',
        id : 'companyCombo',
        fieldLabel : 'Company',
        name : 'COMPANY_ID',
        store: companyStore,
        pageSize: 25,
        displayField : 'COMPANYNAME',
        valueField : 'COMPANY_ID',
        typeAhead : true,
        queryMode : 'local',
        forceSelection : true,
        allowBlank : false,
        editable : true
},
```

When using a paging Combo Box with Ajax data, I am advised to first determine (via Ajax) which 'page' the current item is on, and then set the Combo's page to that via:

```
pagingtoolbar.move(pageNumber)
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to get a reference to `pagingtoolbar` for the Combo.  It doesn't seem to correspond to any of the member fields of the object returned via `Ext.getCmp('companyCombo')`...

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer with the checkbox if the answer did answer your question. Up voting isn't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toolbar is on the combo's picker, not the combo itself. Try this:

```
var combo   = Ext.getCmp('companyCombo'),
    toolbar = combo.getPicker().pagingToolbar;
```

Comment: this gives me access to the toolbar, but unfortunately the `move` function doesn't do what I thought it did.  Instead of skipping to a specific page, this method 'move's components within the toolbar.  Is there a method to have the toolbar skip to a specific page?

Comment: Get the store from the combo (or paging toolbar) and use the `loadPage` method on that store. The store also has `nextPage` and `previousPage` methods.